# Segmentation fault in gSoap client

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gsoap

I'm using gSoap for fetch the server's TimeZone from exchange server, My client code is:

```
#include "soapExchangeServiceBindingProxy.h"
#include "ExchangeServiceBinding.nsmap"


int main()
{
    ExchangeServiceBindingProxy service;
    service.soap_endpoint = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";

    ns1__GetServerTimeZonesType request;
    __ns1__GetServerTimeZonesResponse response;


    const std::string s("Eastern Standard Time");
    request.Ids = (ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType *)&s;



    if(service.GetServerTimeZones(&request , response) == SOAP_OK){

        std::cout << "Success Response: "<< response.ns1__GetServerTimeZonesResponse << std::endl;
    }
    else
      service.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr); 
   service.destroy(); // delete data and release memory 

   return 0;
}
```

This code compiled successfully but when i tried to run it, it give Segmentation fault, I'm newbie in C++ and gSoap also so i don't know exactly what am i doing wrong here?

If you need more code for this, i'll surly provide it to you, please let me know for this. Any help appreciated. thank you.

Comment: `This code compiled successfully but when i tried to run it,`  Successful compilation only means that your program has no syntax errors, and all the function calls have been resolved.  It has no bearing on whether the program will run correctly with respect to your requirements.  That's what debugging is all about.

Comment: `it give Segmentation fault,`  Which line gives the segmentation fault?

Comment: thank you Paul, i think i have this segfault due to auth. on exchange server for fetch data.

Comment: This looks suspicious, and I have never used gSoap:  `const std::string s("Eastern Standard Time"); request.Ids = (ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType *)&s;`  Passing the address of a `std::string` in addition to casting it requires the receiver (`request.Ids`) to understand what a `std::string` is so as to cast it back to `std::string` and use it properly.   This type of coding is done if either your code will "unpack" the value to a `std::string`, or the toolkit itself knows what to do with it.  I don't see an indication of either scenario -- maybe you can explain.

Comment: if i remove cast, i have an error `error: cannot convert ‘const std::string*’ to ‘ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType*’ in assignment
`

Comment: So what exactly is an `ns2_NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType`?  The compiler's error shouldn't be masked by casting -- it could be the reason why your code is having an issue.  Always make sure you know **exactly** why such a cast is valid, because if you put it there just to "shut the compiler up", remove it and research again.

Comment: Usually that means you shouldn't do it. Like hammering the square peg into the round hole of a child's shape-matching toy. You can do it, but the results are most often bad. In this case you told the compiler to ignore the size and shape of a `string`, and use it as you would  `ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType`. Unless there is an established relationship between two classes this is like putting triangular wheels on a car.

Comment: since here i'm trying follow the concept from this C# code [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.getservertimezonestype(v=exchg.150).aspx) , so this casting i've done from `gstzRequest.Ids = new string[] { "Eastern Standard Time", "Pacific Standard Time" };` in the example code of this link into c++ code.

Comment: @hacktushar `since here i'm trying follow the concept from this C# code`  Noooooo.... C++ is **not** C#.  A `string` in C# has absolutely nothing to do with `std::string` from C++.  Look at the `gSoap` documentation for `C` or `C++` examples.  And in general don't use C# as a guide in writing C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how should i pass the string request in it. and this link for `ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType` class [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6qgveihbbs3cnm/code.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Following the concept is OK, but consider that the function may not be supported in C++. If it is, you would to pass in an array of strings: `const std::string s[] = {"Eastern Standard Time"};`, but note the C++ array is a different beast from a C# array. It may not fit.

Comment: @user4581301  according to you i've got ` error: cannot convert ‘const std::string (*)[1]’ to ‘ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType*’ in assignment
` error

Comment: @hacktushar All I can tell you is casting is not an option.  That error means a lot, and it should never have been casted away.  I would bet that this is the cause of your segmentation fault, with the fix being -- read the documentation and look at bonafide C or C++ samples of what you want to do.  A `std::string` cannot just be used as if it's an `int` or `double` -- see my comment about "looking suspicious".

Comment: That tell you the C# array and the C++ array are too different and you are going to have to find another way to accomplish your goal. If you dig into the header file you included for access to the function, you may find what a `ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType` equates to in C++.

Comment: Another experiment is to construct a `ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType` and see what sort of options it makes available to intellisence or the equivalent in your IDE.

Comment: @hacktushar Sorry, I cannot get to that link with the definition of `ns2__NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm sharing a link for whole connect.h header file which help in service operation of gSoap. you can search in it with tag of **GetServerTimeZones**.  [connect.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zvr0l4oqgqmvk0/connect.h?dl=0)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah! i found that in connect.h file the class of `NonEmptyArrayOfTimeZoneIdType` have a string vector, so can i use code like `std::vector< std::string >  Id; request.Id.push_back("Eastern Standard Time");`

Comment: @hacktushar ok.  But make sure that the parameter need not be casted.  That was really the important point, and that was eliminate the casting.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok. i'll take care of it and thank you very much for your precious time.